# TFS Build - Treat compiler warnings as errors?

Tags: tfsbuild

Is there a way to enforce "Treat warnings as errors" on the TFS Build level?  I know you can do this on a project by project basis, but need to enforce on the TFS level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It's always scoped to the build definition.

If you're using TFS2010 you might want to look at altering the default process template so that you don't have to make the same change in every build definition you have.

Comment: any idea why TFS Setting:  "MsBuild Arguments" to /p:WarnAsError="true"  doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

@felickz

you need to use this setting. so that all your warnings would get treated as error

**/p:TreatWarningsAsErrors="true"**

i used this setting and its working for me.